# How to get the Ubuntu-dictionary in Lubuntu?

Tags: dictionary

It seems that Ubuntu-desktop comes with a dictionary. What is that and how to get that In Lubuntu?

Comment: Nothing in my Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @green7 that is an online dictionary, so you may have not noticed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are referring to `gnome-dictionary`, which you can install with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-dictionary
```

<sub>Refs:</sub>

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dictionary&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gnome-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Golden Dictionary is heavier (larger) but seems to work well behind a firewall, which seemed to block gnome-dictionary.
Installation

```
sudo apt-get install goldendict
```

And in Edit-Dictionaries you may add a variety of sources to consult